# Conditional operator not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, conditional-operator

I have the following code where I am using a Conditional Operator to look for null values and assign another value if a null is found.  My problem is that it isn't detecting the null value correctly for some reason.

```
sliderQuestion11.Value = Convert.ToDouble(cs.q11 != null ? cs.q11 : "10");
```

cs is a class populated by a SQLite query and q11 is a string.

I get a "Value cannot be null" error.  Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help everyone.  All those answers should have worked but what I had to do is instead of just returning

```
query.FirstOrDefault()
```

I had to do the following

```
CustomerSurvey cs = new CustomerSurvey();
cs.q1 = query.FirstOrDefault().q1 ?? "-10";
cs.q2 = query.FirstOrDefault().q2 ?? "-10";
cs.q3 = query.FirstOrDefault().q3 ?? "-10";                        
cs.srID = query.FirstOrDefault().srID;
```

Now this works

```
sliderQuestion11.Value = Convert.ToDouble(cs.q11 != "-10" ? cs.q11 : "10");
```

(I know you are going to say why not just set it to 10 but I need to detect a null value elsewhere in the code. That is why I'm using -10)

Comment: Note that an empty string isn't a `null`. Is there a reason that you chose not to use the [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator?

Comment: try `Convert.ToDouble(!IsNullOrEmpty(cs.q11) ? cs.q11 : "10");`

Comment: I tried the ?? operator.  I use that and the conditional operators all the time but in this case no matter what I do I get a "Value cannot be null" error.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cs.q11) ? cs.qll : "10";
```

The reason for using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is because the string may just be empty rather than `null`.

Full snippet:

```
sliderQuestion11.Value = Convert.ToDouble(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cs.q11) ? cs.qll : "10");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this code:

```
sliderQuestion11.Value = Convert.ToDouble(cs.q11 ?? "10");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it should be

```
sliderQuestion11.Value = (cs != null && (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(cs.q11)) ? Convert.ToDouble(cs.q11) : 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sliderQuestion11.Value = Convert.ToDouble(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cs.q11) ? cs.q11 : "10");
```

This would also check that the string does not contain just 1 or more whitespaces, in addition to the null and empty checks.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer: :)

```
sliderQuestion11.Value = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(cs.q11) ? 10.0 : Convert.ToDouble(cs.q11);
```